# cover pagereference method in test class and there is no pagename mention only /+lead.id mention

Tags: apex, unit-test, pagereference

this is class code

```
public pagereference AcceptLeadFromDetail(){

        AcceptLeadButtonSupport((new list<Id>{objLead.Id}));

        if(bShowAcceptMessage)
            return null;

        pagereference redpg = new pagereference('/'+this.objLead.Id);
        redpg.setRedirect(true);
        return redpg;

    }
```

this is i am trying in test but given error there is no pagename directly pass lead id in class so how to call this

```
PageReference pageref = page.'/'+leadRecord.Id;

pageref.AcceptLeadFromDetail();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test class just call this method

```
AcceptLeadFromDetail
```

And set this to false before calling the method

```
bShowAcceptMessage = false;
```

You can also use `assert` statements to validate this

```
 system.assert(AcceptLeadFromDetail() != null);
```